# C# how to determine if the Request is not coming from an asset url, like image or css for example

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to do something like this:

```
if(Request == "mainPath")
{
//code here
}
```

So for example if the Request is coming from http://www.mydomain.com/tax/tax1 it would return true, but if Request is coming from http://www.mydomian.com/tax/tax1/image5.jpg or template.css it will not. What would be the best way to do it? I guess I could compare the url that's in the browser with the full path of the request but I am not sure if it's the best idea. Also, if it has any value to the question, the code exists in Application_BeginRequest() in Global.asax.cs - MVC3 project.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you intend to tell the difference? By extension?

Comment: I don't know, that's basically the question. What do you think? Is doing that by extension good? `if(extensions is null || "") { run the code }` - like this?

Comment: That depends on your site and your URLs.

Comment: Yeah I don't have any pages that would show extensions, unless you specifically open that image, css or a document. Other than that, it's in MVC3 so there are no extensions in urls.

Comment: What is the underlying goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to check the extension of the requested URL.
Check `Path.GetExtension(Request.Url.LocalPath)`.

You might also want to check `File.Exists(Server.MapPath(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ContentType of Request. For resources like image you will get image/jpeg. you can determine which type of requesting is coming.

The correct Content-Type values should be

text/css -> for .css files

image/gif -> for .gif files

image/jpeg -> for .jpg/.jpeg files

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you open an image directly, you won't get a content type.